# Passing Map as (flatMap) mapping function causes error

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a map:

```
  val mnem = Map(
    '2' -> "ABC", '3' -> "DEF", '4' -> "GHI", '5' -> "JKL",
    '6' -> "MNO", '7' -> "PQRS", '8' -> "TUV", '9' -> "WXYZ")
```

I'm curious why I can't pass this map as a mapping function considering that a Map is both a collection and a function such as below

```
val digits = "2345"                       //> digits  : String = 2345

digits flatMap mnem                       //> ERROR
```

But I can do this

```
digits flatMap(mnem(_))                   //> res0: String = ABCDEFGHIJKL
```

I was trying to do something analogous to this:

```
digits map mnem                           //> res1: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(ABC, DEF, GHI, 
                                              //| JKL)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Map[Char, String]` is a function `(Char => String)`.

```
trait Map[A, +B] extends ... MapLike[A, B, Map[A, B]] 
trait MapLike[A, +B, ...] extends PartialFunction[A, B] ...
trait PartialFunction[-A, +B] extends (A) ⇒ B
```

This works fine:

```
val f: Char => String = mnem
```

You'll get the same error with `digits flatMap f`.

`flatMap` on `String` takes `Char ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B]` as parameter. And `String` is not a `GenTraversableOnce`, so `(Char => String)` (and `Map[Char, String]`) is not `Char ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B]`.

Scala rewrites `Map.apply` and `Map(_)` as `x => Map(x)` **and then** applies an implicit conversion to function result:

```
x => augmentString(Map(x))
```

It can convert `Map(x)` to get function of type `Char ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[Char]`, but it can't convert existing function of type `Char => String` to `Char ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[Char]` since there is no such implicit conversion is scope.

Answer (score 3):

To get the equivalent of the line

```
digits flatMap(mnem(_)) // mnem's apply method is the actual method passed to flatMap
```

you want

```
digits flatMap mnem.apply
```

Answer (score -1):

Because `Map` is not a *function*, rather object of Map can act as a *method* due to `apply` method defined in `Map`. `flatMap` need a function (not a method), that's why you need to use `mnem(_)` to convert it to a function.

Comment: this is really informative. Any idea why flatMap was designed like this?

Comment: `Map` is a function. Your answer is just incorrect. See my answer.